# Determine NPM modules used from a running node.js application

Tags: node.js, npm

Other than grabbing the `package.json` file at the project root is there a way to determine the list of dependencies of a running node.js application? Does node keep this meta information available as some var in the global namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just looking for the currently installed npm packages in the application directory, then you can install the [npm](http://search.npmjs.org/#/npm) package (`npm install -g npm`) and [programatically](http://npmjs.org/api/npm.html) invoke [`ls`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/doc/api/ls.md) to list the installed packages and the dependency trees.

*Obviously, this has no bearing on whether the installed packages are actually `require`'d in the application or not.*

Usage is not that well documented but this should get you started.

```
var npm = require('npm');

npm.load(function(err, npm) {
    npm.commands.ls([], true, function(err, data, lite) {
        console.log(data); //or lite for simplified output
    });
});
```

e.g.:

```
{ dependencies:
   { npm: { version: '1.1.18', dependencies: [Object] },
     request: { version: '2.9.202' } } }
```

Otherwise, I believe the only other option is to  introspect the [`module`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) module to get information pertaining to the currently loaded/cached module paths. However this definitely does not look to have been developed as a public API. I'm not sure if there are any alternatives so would be keen to hear if there are e.g.

```
var req = require('request'); // require some module for demo purposes
var m = require('module');

// properties of m contain current loaded module info, e.g. m._cache
```

Comment: This looks workable.I'm going to leave the question open for a little longer to see if anyone else has suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth asking on the node.js IRC channel as well.. http://nodejs.org/community/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use [require-analyzer](https://github.com/nodejitsu/require-analyzer), which sort of works according to [Isaacs](https://github.com/isaacs)(could miss some). You could hear this in [Nodeup's first podcast](http://nodeup.com/one) from 11:55.

Or you could try James [node-detective](https://github.com/substack/node-detective) which probably will find your dependencies better(but not by running code), but because of Javascript dynamic nature(12:46).

> **detective**
>
> Find all calls to require() no matter how crazily nested using a
>   proper walk of the AST.

P.S: to expose those package.json variables to node.js you could use [node-pkginfo](https://github.com/indexzero/node-pkginfo)